# django 1.8 CreateView Error

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.8 to create a login form. But the template containing registration form does not render properly.

my `views.py`

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    RegistrationForm = UserCreationForm
    fields = ['username','password1','password2']
    model = User
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
```

my `forms.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, ButtonHolder, Submit

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        'username',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        ButtonHolder(
            Submit('register', 'Register', css_class='btn-primary')
        )
    )
```

`signup.html`

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Register | {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block headline %}<h1>Registration form</h1>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

The template renders but without the submit button.I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SignUpView` is not specifying the form it should render, you need to add the `form_class` attribute.

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    model = User
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
```